# What does it mean: ".. if the Neumann problem is to have a solution"

Tags: meaning

I am reading a mathematical book with the title of "[The Numerical Solution of Integral Equations of the Second Kind](https://books.google.com/books?id=hNFNPwAACAAJ&dq=isbn:0521102839&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH1bLJ4NjJAhWCDhoKHX_LAv4Q6AEIHTAA)." In the penultimate paragraph of the page 309, you read:

> The identity (7.1.6) can be used to prove (i) if the Neumann problem (7.1.3)
>   has a solution, then it is unique up to the addition of an arbitrary constant; and (ii) **if the Neumann problem is to have a solution**, then the condition (7.1.4) is necessary.

The indicated part is really unclear to me; what does it mean?

Comment: (7.1.4) is a necessary condition for there to be a solution to the Neumann problem. If condition (7.1.4) is **not** fulfilled, the Neumann problem has no solution.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the reply, do you imply that it means that if the Neumann problem needs to have a solution, then that condition must met, or what?! I don't know what does "if sth is to have.." mean :(

Comment: Compare: *If we are to have any chance of winning this game against the league leaders, our best players must be healthy and off the injured list.* In other words, *unless* our  best players are healthy, we have no chance of winning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have difficulty in understanding ***be + to-infinitive*** which is broadly used to express *things that should be done*, *official orders* and *a possible aim*, etc.

You can visit the [link](http://www.grammaring.com/be-to-infinitive) which explains about it in detail.

Now, your example:

> if the Neumann problem ***is to have*** a solution, then the condition
>   (7.1.4) is necessary

It could be rephrased to:

> in order for the Neumann problem to have a solution the condition
>   (7.1.4) is necessary.

The *be + to-infinitive*, ***is to have***, in your example is used to express *a possible aim when saying what should be done to reach it* (the 4th example in the link).

> If you ***are to work*** here for more than three months, you must have a
>   residence permit.

[Grammaring.Com]

Comment: _"To express a possible aim;"_ that's what I've missed, thank you very much :)

Comment: @goodUser My pleasure.